# Installing PCNTL module for PHP7.4 on Amazon Linux

Tags: php7, php.ini, amazon-linux, extension, laravel

I'm using amazon linux2 and trying to install `pcntl` extension for php7.4.9. There are no package for `pcntl` after run `yum search pcntl`, so
I manually copied file `pcntl.so` to `/usr/lib64/php/modules` and created `/etc/php.d/20-pcntl.ini,` file.

But I got error `PHP Warning:  Module 'pcntl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0`

```
# php -r "print_r(get_loaded_extensions());"
Array
(
    [0] => Core
    [1] => date
    [2] => libxml
    [3] => openssl
    [4] => pcre
    [5] => zlib
    [6] => filter
    [7] => hash
    [8] => pcntl
    [9] => readline
    [10] => Reflection
    [11] => SPL
    [12] => session
    [13] => standard
    [14] => bcmath
    [15] => bz2
    [16] => calendar
    [17] => ctype
    [18] => curl
    [19] => dom
    [20] => mbstring
    [21] => fileinfo
    [22] => ftp
    [23] => gd
    [24] => gettext
    [25] => iconv
    [26] => intl
    [27] => json
    [28] => exif
    [29] => mysqlnd
    [30] => PDO
    [31] => Phar
    [32] => posix
    [33] => shmop
    [34] => SimpleXML
    [35] => sockets
    [36] => sqlite3
    [37] => sysvmsg
    [38] => sysvsem
    [39] => sysvshm
    [40] => tokenizer
    [41] => xml
    [42] => xmlwriter
    [43] => xsl
    [44] => zip
    [45] => mysqli
    [46] => pdo_mysql
    [47] => pdo_sqlite
    [48] => xmlreader
)
```

So I can't use function `pcntl_async_signals`. Where was my config wrong?

Comment: It sounds like it is already installed. What is the real problem you had?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I guess that, PHP CLI and PHP FPM is different. But they are using same php.ini file